# Unable to display error message before redirecting to new page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display an error message before redirecting the page from a hidden field. I'm not successful in doing it.
Below is the code -
**HTML**

```
<form name="formlogin" method="get" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();" class="form-wrapper">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="service-lable" style="font-family:Verdana;">Username</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="email" name="username" maxlength="30" size="30" class="required"/> <br/><br/>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="service-lable" style="font-family:Verdana;">Password</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="password" name="password"maxlength="30" size="30" class="required"/> <br/><br/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="directlogin" id="directlogin" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="returnfailure" id="returnfailure" value="http://www.google.com"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit"  name="login" value="" class="button_add" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
        function emailcheck(str) {
            var at="@";
            var dot=".";
            var lat=str.indexOf(at);
            var lstr=str.length;
            var ldot=str.indexOf(dot);


            if (lat ==-1 || lat == 0 || lat == lstr){
                return false;
            }
            if (ldot==-1 || ldot==0 || ldot == lstr){
                return false;
            }

            if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
                return false;
            }

            if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot){
                return false;
            }

            if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1){
                return false;
            }

            if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
                return false;
            }
            return true;                    
        }

        function ValidateForm(){
            var emailID=document.forms["formlogin"].username;
            var username=document.forms["formlogin"].username.value;
            username=username.toLowerCase();
            var password=document.forms["formlogin"].password.value;



            if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value == "")){
//      alert("Please Enter your Email ID");
        emailID.focus();
        return false;
            }
            if (emailcheck(emailID.value)== true){
                document.forms["formlogin"].action = "http://www.test.com/login.jsf";
        return true;
            } else {
                alert ('Please enter the valid Email ID');
        return false ;

            }
        }
    </script>
```

- Scenario 1

When login is successful the page redirects to another site, which **works**

- Scenario 2

If login fails then it should redirect to page where value of  returnfailure is mentioned.
This works, but I'm not able to display the error message before redirecting. How can I do this with hidden field.

Comment: Where is your redirection code

Comment: @sandeepproop see in validateform()

Comment: is the redirection code after this line: alert ('Please enter the valid Email ID'); ?

Comment: @Mr.Cocococo success redirection is in valdationform(), failure redirection is in hiddenfield(returnfailure) value

Comment: where is the code to get the value from hiddenfield and redirect to it? I cant see one.

Comment: @Mr.Cocococo I don't see any code.It redirects to returnfailure value automatically if login fails. Is there a way to display an alert box before redirection

Answer (score 0):

Update your following code

```
function ValidateForm(){
        var emailID=document.forms["formlogin"].username;
        var username=document.forms["formlogin"].username.value;
        username=username.toLowerCase();
        var password=document.forms["formlogin"].password.value;



        if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value == "")){
          //alert("Please Enter your Email ID");
          emailID.focus();
          return false;
        }
        if (emailcheck(emailID.value)== true){
            document.forms["formlogin"].action = "http://www.test.com/login.jsf";
            return true;
        } else {
            alert ('Please enter the valid Email ID');
            window.location.href = document.getElementById("returnfailure").value;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the login success or failure is decided by 'http://www.test.com/login.jsf'.
The logic to handle the redirection must be in that file.

So what you can do is:

1. If login fails -> Redirect to the Login Form Page(page you mentioned above) with an additional request parameter saying that login was failed. (This code should go inside 'http://www.test.com/login.jsf')
2. Use that request parameter value inside the Login page, to display or hide the error message.
3. If you displayed the error then redirect into the page you mentioned in 'returnfailure' hidden field

Comment: Hi, What you said is absolutely right, is it not possible to do this before redirection in client side with a flag or so

Comment: @user3004356  Yes, it's possible. But somehow you have to get the login success/fail result to the client side before the page redirects. I think the best way to do this is using an ajax request to submit the login data (after validating) to 'http://www.test.com/login.jsf'. Based on the ajax response you can make a javascript call to redirect the page. Since default submit action refreshes the page make sure it won't fire.